# removing "index.php" from CodeIgniter multiple sub-directories down

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I know this has been asked many times before, but the previous solutions/answers aren't working.

I have viewed these:

- [Remove index.php From URL - Codeigniter 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155333/remove-index-php-from-url-codeigniter-2)
- [mod_rewrite to remove index.php from Codeigniter in subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540524/mod-rewrite-to-remove-index-php-from-codeigniter-in-subdirectory)
- [Using htaccess to remove codeigniter index.php in a subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765883/using-htaccess-to-remove-codeigniter-index-php-in-a-subdirectory)

I have used these solutions successfully in the past, but this install is giving me problems.  I am thinking this might be more than an `.htaccess` issue.

**Description**

My folder setup is as follows: `/home/~username~/public_html/~company~/index.php`. My `$config['index_page']` is set to `""` and my server has mod_rewrite enabled. I am using `CI version, 2.1.3`

The `.htaccess` file is located in the same folder as the `application` folder.

**Problem**

I can't seem to remove the `index.php` from my URL without the application breaking. I have tried many, many `.htaccess` setups, including the one provided on the CI website.

I am at a loss. If it's not my `.htaccess` file, what could it be? If it is my `.htaccess` file, what am I doing wrong? My latest attempts are these:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php) [NC]    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/username/company/index.php/$1 [L] //absolute path
and
""
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ company/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Full `apache` error:

```
[Thu Jan 24 18:22:13 2013] [error] [client ip ] 
File does not exist: /home/username/public_html/company/home
```

Comment: 1. You say you're "90% sure". Can you use `apache_get_modules()` or something to be 100% sure? 2. Your RewriteRule is missing public_html, is that intentional?

Comment: 1. I ran that function and it is indeed installed. 2. I tried with public_html and without, no difference.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message you get when you remove index.php from the URL? (It could be in either the apache error log OR the CI application log.)

Comment: I don't have access to the apache log and the CI `application/log` only has an empty `index.html` file.

Comment: It's probably to do with your host's apache setup, but it's going to be really difficult to debug without seeing the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Set the variable empty as below.

`$config['index_page'] = '';`

try to replace following variable with these parameters `('AUTO', 'PATH_INFO', 'QUERY_STRING', 'REQUEST_URI', and 'ORIG_PATH_INFO')` one by one

`$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';`

Comment: with what `.htaccess` configuration?

Comment: the one in the same folder as application folder

Comment: what do you mean? I am trying to figure out what `.htaccess` file setup I should use.

Comment: the one you are currently using seems right for me, the solution i suggesting here for the this "I can't seem to remove the index.php from my URL without the application breaking"